# Understanding the proof of: if A Connected and $ A \subset B \subset \bar{A} \Rightarrow B$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

I shall write the proof of this following theorem, which i have found on the internet. i shall mark the part which i do not understand.

The proof is done by contradiction:

Let $B$ be not connected, thus there exists open, disjunct none empty sets $U, V$ such that $B \subset U \cup V  $ with $B \cap U$ and $B \cap V$ non-empty.
Because $ A \subset B $ then obviously $A \subset U \cup V $.
Furthermore are the intersections $ A \cap V $ and $ A \cap U $ none empty. For if for example $ A \cap U = \emptyset  $ then $A \subset X-U$ then because $ X - U $ is closed (Because $U$ is open) we have

1. $ B \subset \bar{A} \subset X-U$

This is however is a contradiction to the fact that $B \cap U \neq \emptyset $

Analog we find that $ A \cap V$ is not empty

But then  $ V , U $ would disassemble A then A would not be connected which is a contradiction.

What i do not understand is marked as equation (1). Why does $\bar{A} \subset X-U$ ?
The rest of the proof is clear to me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure $\overline{A}$ of $A$ in $X$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ containing $A$. More precisely, it is the intersection of all closed subsets of $X$ containing $A$ and thus contained in every closed subset containing $A$. In your case the set $X - U$ is closed so that $A \subset X - U$ implies $\overline{A} \subset X - U$.

Comment: Interesting, does Generally speaking $ A \subset B $ where as B closed thus we write $ A \subset B = \bar {B} $ imply  that $ \bar{A} \subset B  = \bar {B}$ ?

Comment: @MadSpaces Yes.

Comment: Thank your for explaining.

Comment: @MadSpaces : Maybe even a bit more general, $A \subset B$ implies $\overline{A} \subset \overline{B}$ for any $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You are right @MatthiasKlupsch. Thanks